# What is the relationship between: $\det(A + E[i,i]) = \det(A) + \det(A')$ and multilinearity?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, linear-transformations, determinant, multilinear-algebra

Studying graph theory I came across the proof of Kirchof's theorem for maximal trees ("The number of generating trees of a graph $G$ is equal to the determinant of the reduced Laplacian Matrix of $G$"), according to author Richard Stanley, it is necessary to apply a property of the determinant called multilinearity property, specifically:
Given a matrix sum of the form **(Eq1)** $A_1 = A + E[i,i]$, its determinant can be expressed as: **(Eq1)** $\det(A_1) = \det(A) + \det(A')$ with $E[i, i]$ the matrix of the same dimensions of $A$ but with the entry $(i,i)$ as $1$, and all other entries equal to $0$, while $A'$ is the submatrix of $A$ with row and column $i$ eliminated. How to obtain these matrices is clear to me but my question is:

**1)** How is this property of multilinearity deduced?

**2)** What does it mean that the determinant is multilinear and how is this implied, specifically with **(Eq1)**?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To prove Equation1 all you need to do is to expand the determinant along the $i$th row (or column). If you insist on using multilinearity then think of the $i$th row (or column)  of $A_1$ as the sum of the $i$th row of $A$, and a vector with single $1$ and $n-1$ zeros.